# What happens to the previous foreground job, when command fg a new job?

Tags: linux, shell, jobs

A shell can only have one foreground job at a time. When using fg to place a job to the foreground, what would happen to the previous running foreground job? Will the shell send a SIGTSTP to it, and change job state? Or will it just be put to the background by bg?

Comment: To use the shell to issue the `bg` shell, the foreground process needs to be stopped, such as by ^Z.  This sends the SIGTSTP to the foreground process so it doesn't interfere with the shell while it's prompting for input.  For more on what happens when you `bg` that formerly foreground process, see [details on foreground process groups in this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/594141/what-determines-whether-a-scripts-background-processes-get-a-terminals-sigint).

Answer (score 0):

To start a job in the foreground in the same shell the previous job first needs to be send to the background with `CTRL+Z` and `bg`. If you omit `bg`, the previous foreground job sent back with `CTRL+Z` would still be stopped (understood as: paused, not getting any processing time).

*In other words:* I am not aware of a way to place another **foreground job** in a shell, when another job is **already running** in the foreground of that **same shell**, because the stdin is used by the running foreground job.

Example:

```
$ sleep 4223
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 sleep 4223
$ bg
[1]+ sleep 4223 &
$ sleep 1234
^Z
[2]+  Stopped                 sleep 1234
$ jobs 
[1]-  Running                 sleep 4223 &
[2]+  Stopped                 sleep 1234
$ fg 1
sleep 4223
fg 2  # this command has no effect, stdin is used by job 1
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 sleep 4223
$ jobs
[1]+  Stopped                 sleep 4223
[2]-  Stopped                 sleep 1234
$ bg
[1]+ sleep 4223 &
```

Comment: What if I keep running and ctrl-z, and I don't use bg? I guess it would cause lots and lots of processes to stop. It seems to be a problem.

Comment: It would only stop (pause) the process you are sending in the background with `CTRL+Z`.